# weird piece of code

Tags: c++

I have written this little weird piece of code. How is this possible that `type` changes between its 2 `printf` ??

Thanks in advance

```
int main()
{
    string label = string("faults_team_A_player_12");

    size_t f = label.find('_');

    const char *type = label.substr(0,f).c_str();
    const char team = label.at(f+sizeof("team_"));

    printf("type = %s\n",type);

    int n;
    size_t l = label.length()-label.find_last_of('_');

    int x = sscanf((char *)label.substr(label.find_last_of('_'),l).c_str(),"_%d",&n);
    printf("type = %s\n",type);
    printf("team = %c\n",team);
    printf("player = %d\n",n);

    return 0;
}
```

ouptut:

```
type = faults
type = _12
team = A
player = 12
```

Comment: I don't quite understand why the downvote or the request to close...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`type` is a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) as it is initialised to the internal member of a temporary `std::string` instance:

```
const char *type = label.substr(0,f).c_str();
```

The `std::string` instance from which the result of `c_str()` is obtained is destructed immediately.

Answer (score 3):

```
const char *type = label.substr(0,f).c_str();
```

The pointer `type` refers to a piece of data inside a temporary (`label.substr(0,f)`). Any use of that pointer is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a pointer to `std::string`'s buffer by calling `.c_str()` you don't acquire the buffer. When, for example, the string object goes out of scope, the pointer is invalidated.